# PHP function argument

Tags: php, function

I want make function with 3 parameter, first parameter is `$field`, second parameter is `$condition` and last parameter is `$value`.
the function what I make like this:

```
function where($field, $condition = ' = ', $value);
```

i want call the function run with this code :

`->where('name', 'andi')`

and condition will be the default **( = )**.

it's easy if $condition in last parameter, but i want $condition in middle.

if i call the function only with 2 parameter, how to know second parameter is $value not $condition ?
any idea ?

thank you in advance.

SOLVED with [func_num_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php)

Comment: no, its different case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. You cannot have default arguments hanging in the middle of the arguments. Check the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

If you insist on putting it in the middle, make your `$value` to be null as default too, such that it become like this:

```
function where($field, $condition = ' = ', $value = null);
```

Similar to how laravel did it: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/91622fc886baf6263de9f93237929dcc5d61537c/Query/Builder.php#L480

In order to know whether you are dealing with `where($field, $conditions, $value)` ,or `where($field, $value)`, you do a simple argument counts using [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php), to know that which calls are you dealing with.

Comment: but laravel have function like that on eloquent.

Comment: i dont understand, if i call the function only with 2 parameter, how to know second parameter is $value not $condition ?

Comment: I'm sorry for wrong link reference. Check the link in the answer again. There is logic on "how to know 2nd parameter is value not condition"